# Passing column name as a parameter in mysql stored function

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am using a MySQL stored function where I have created a function and I have passed column name as a parameter to this function. Suppose

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `test_func`(column_1 varchar(100)) RETURNS varchar(100) CHARSET latin1

select column_1 from table where id = 1 ;
```

Here I want to get the value of column 'column_1' with id 1. But I am getting the column name itself not the value.

Please help me to write the correct syntax.

Answer (score 6):

There are couple of problems with your approach. First of all you can't use your argument *value* to reference the underlying column. Good thing is that you can use [Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) as workaround for this.

Second problem is that MySQL functions don't allow use of Prepared Statements. To workaround that limitation you need to use Stored Procedures instead. As an example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test_func (IN col1 varchar(100), OUT res int)
BEGIN

SET @s=CONCAT('SELECT ',col1,' INTO @res FROM yourtable WHERE id=1');
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

SELECT @res INTO res;

END
```

Answer (score 3):

After a long search I found that a stored function can be used only to return a single value or a calculated answer (Arithmetic). For your query just use a stored procedure. It is as simple as creating a query from the front end. And here is the syntax:

Use `CONCAT(X1,X2,X3 . . .)` to do it as you would like.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Test`(table longtext,column longtext,e_id longtext)

SET @s=CONCAT('Select ',table,' from ', column, 'Where employee = ',e_id);

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s;

EXECUTE stmt1;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

END
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to ask. But here is a solution using Prepared Statements:

```
SET @selectStatement = CONCAT('Select ', columnName1,' from tab1 where id = 1'); -- Build Select statement like this
PREPARE stmt FROM @selectStatement; -- parse and prepare insert statement from the above string 
EXECUTE stmt; -- execute statement
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt; -- release the statement memory.
```

I don't know the complete scenario, but this may be avoided by changing some design.